# How To Access The Graph API After Using A FB:Login-Button?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm sure I got this to work in the past, but for some reason I'm having trouble finding out how to do it now...

I have users logging into an application and granting permissions using the button provided by Facebook:

```
<fb:login-button perms="email,publish_stream">Login</fb:login-button>
```

Thereafter, suppose I want to try to post something to their wall.  Do I need to extract an access code at the end of the login process?  Is there a redirect-uri that the login process sends the access code to - if so I can't immediately find this for my app, where is it set?  Facebook's Developers documentation is good to a point but ultimately frustrating for me... am I looking at the wrong section there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aha, looks like I've found it: Facebook automatically stores the details for the logged in user, including the access token, in a cookie called fbs_YOUR_APP_ID.  So I should be able to get what I need out of that.  As you were!